# Serve containerized wordpress with nginx

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx

I have a server with nginx installed, and multiple containers, I want that nginx will direct the requests to the appropriate container.
One of the containers is Wordpress container that exposes port 8000:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: **
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: **
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: **

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: **
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: **
volumes:
    db_data:
```

I'm successfully entering to the Wordpress instance in the address: `http://my_wordpress.com:8000`.
How I should configure my nginx so when I'll request `http://my_wordpress.com` it will forward the request to the WordPress?
My current `wordpress.conf`:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my_wordpress.com;
        return 301 https://my_wordpress.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl spdy; 
        server_name my_wordpress.com;
        ssl_certificate ***********.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key ***************.pem;
        ssl_protocols ***************;
        ssl_ciphers '*******************';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass my_wordpress.com:8000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
}
```

Comment: Where does this `wordpress.conf` reside?

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov `/etc/nginx/conf.d/wordpress.conf`

Comment: I am curious how your working Wordpress displays static files, e.g. CSS, images, etc. Is everything OK with them?

Comment: Thanks! Wordpress render the static assets with a wrong URL, See my answer for more info.

Comment: The belongs to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didn't knows that when I open this question. What should I do? Delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the hostname config in Wordpress settings to: `https://my_wordpress.com`.

Eventually, it turned out that Wordpress states its hostname by config, the default config (after Wordpress installation) was: `http://my_wordpress.com:8000` so the Wordpress redirect from `https://my_wordpress.com` to `http://my_wordpress.com:8000` and it made a lot of troubles.

Because I'm a newbie to Nginx, docker, AND Wordpress I confused and thought that Wordpress take the hostname according to what it got from the server and the problem is on the server configuration level.

For reference, this is the working `wordpress.conf`:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my_wordpress.com;
        return 301 https://my_wordpress.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name my_wordpress.com;
        ssl_certificate ***************.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key **************.pem;
        ssl_protocols ************;
        ssl_ciphers '*********';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) which automatically creates a reverse proxy of the containers you want to expose. It's very simple and fast to use.

So, for example, your deployment would be:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   nginx-proxy:
     image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     volumes:
       - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: **
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: **
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: **

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: **
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: **
       VIRTUAL_HOST=my_wordpress.local
volumes:
    db_data:
```

Comment: Thanks! But I didn't want to have Nginx in the container. Also, I discover later that the image already contains Apache. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: **
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: **
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: **
    networks:
      - my_network

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: **
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: **
    networks:
      - my_network

  nginx:
    image: nginx_revpxy    
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfileForNginx
    networks:
      - my_network

network:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge

# DockerfileForNginx file
# 
# FROM nginx:alpine
# RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/


# Example of nginx.conf
# server {
#         listen 80;
#         server_name wordpress;
#         return 301 https://my_wordpress.com$request_uri;
# }
```

If you setup the network, you can talk to the containers by the service name.  Just make sure you load the right nginx.conf to the docker container and you have a reverse proxy container that will talk to the rest of them in the same docker network.